# how to override generic type in method inside a class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the following code

```
export class NewForm<T> {
  public values: T = {} as any
  private schema: Record<string, any> = {}

  private assembleValues() {
    Object.keys(this.schema).forEach((field) => {
      this.values[field] = ''
    })
  }
}
```

but I get the following error

[image]

works fine if i do something like

```
Object.keys(this.schema).forEach((field) => {
  ;(this.values as Record<string, any>)[field] = ''
})
```

But this is not sustainable as it would repeat a lot in the code, but `Record<string, any>` is exactly what I would like to have as "false" type inside the class itself

What would be the best way to handle this?

Sorry if I couldn't express myself properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "false" type?  Why can't you just make `NewForm` non-generic and have `values` be of type `Record<string, any>`? It sure looks like if `values` is supposed to be of some caller-chosen `T` type then `assembleValues()` is almost certainly going to fail to do the right thing.  Could you provide a [mre] which actually demonstrates something useful happening to motivate these types?

Comment: Also, please remove the "typescript-typings" tag because it does not apply. And please write out the text of your error in the question itself; [code or errors that only appear in images are rarely appropriate here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).